# How to disable "Video in separate window" icon on video

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, opera, yandex

I have a `video` tag on my page for short background seamless looped animation with `muted`,`autoplay` and `loop` tags. I'm looking for a solution to hide this anointing popup icon on both mobile and desktop chromium powered browsers like Opera and Yandex.

I've tried to experiment with shadow `DOM` and pseudo elements - it doesn't work;

```
    video::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
    video::-webkit-media-controls {

        display: none !important;
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;

        #shadow-root,
        #video-detach-button {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
```

[image: video tag in Yandex Browser]
[image: video tag in Opera Browser]

Comment: I guess this is a function from the browser itself. As far as i know there is no possibiliity to remove this.